# How to use navigator.app.exitApp() to exit application in phone gap?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I have an application built using sencha-touch & phonegap but I don't know how to add exit/stop function to exit the application. After looking arround in google and other sites I got clue to use `navigator.app.exitApp()` but it didn't work.

How can I solve this?

Note :
I'm using
- phonegap 1.3
- sencha touch 1.1
- Galaxy tab

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `navigator.app.exitApp()` throwing any errors? First place I would look is to make sure that `<plugin name="App" value="com.phonegap.App"/>` is in your `plugins.xml` file.

Comment: No, there are no any errors I got. When I click the button, there is no response, whereas I place navigator.app.exitApp() on my action button to exit the application but it didn't response

Comment: Would it be possible to upgrade the phonegap version? It seems it gives some problems in old versions (http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/how_to_exit_from_the_phonegap_app_on_android_and_ios)

Comment: How about stop using ST1 and work in ST2?

Answer (score 10):

Please try following code, it is working fine in my app:

```
document.addEventListener("exitButton",function(){ 

    navigator.notification.confirm(
           'Do you want to quit', 
           onConfirmQuit, 
           'QUIT TITLE', 
           'OK,Cancel'  
    );

}, true);

function onConfirmQuit(button){
   if(button == "1"){
     navigator.app.exitApp(); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put something like this in the HTML file:

```
<a href="#" onClick="closeMeNow();" data-role="button">Close App</a>
```

That links to a function like this in your JS file:

```
function closeMeNow() {
    navigator.app.exitApp();
}
```

I know the syntax is more JQM than Sencha, but since the concept is basically the same you can just edit where is needed.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10134499/1606614)

You need to add a listener event for the backbutton and associate a function.

It would be a good idea to update your phonegap/cordova version to the latest build and use the code provided above.

Answer (score 0):

This code like a charm:

```js
Ext.Msg.confirm("Close app?.", 'Close app', function (btn) {
  if (btn == 'yes') {
    navigator.app.exitApp();
  }
});
```