# how to exit android phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova

I need to exit Android Phonegap application by clicking on button
I tried to use this code in onclick event

```
navigator.app.exitApp()
```

but it didn't work and nothing happened, So How to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238

Comment: navigator.app.exitApp() is available from the phonegap 1.8.0 version

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a listener event for the button and associate a function. 
Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123005/close-android-app-jquery-phonegap/10134499#10134499).

It would be a good idea to update your phonegap/cordova version to the latest build and use the code provided above.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade PhoneGap.js, it may be solve your problem